# Equivalent to StringTokenizer with multiple characters delimiters

Tags: java

I try to split a String into tokens.

The token delimiters are not single characters, some delimiters are included into others (example, & and &&), and I need to have the delimiters returned as token.
StringTokenizer is not able to deal with multiple characters delimiters. I presume it's possible with String.split, but fail to guess the magical regular expression that will suits my needs.

Any idea ?

Example:

```
Token delimiters: "&", "&&", "=", "=>", " "  
String to tokenize: a & b&&c=>d  
Expected result: an string array containing "a", " ", "&", " ", "b", "&&", "c", "=>", "d"
```

--- Edit ---
Thanks to all for your help, Dasblinkenlight gives me the solution. Here is the "ready to use" code I wrote with his help:

```
private static String[] wonderfulTokenizer(String string, String[] delimiters) {
  // First, create a regular expression that matches the union of the delimiters
  // Be aware that, in case of delimiters containing others (example && and &),
  // the longer may be before the shorter (&& should be before &) or the regexpr
  // parser will recognize && as two &.
  Arrays.sort(delimiters, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
      return -o1.compareTo(o2);
     }
  });
  // Build a string that will contain the regular expression
  StringBuilder regexpr = new StringBuilder();
  regexpr.append('(');
  for (String delim : delimiters) { // For each delimiter
    if (regexpr.length() != 1) regexpr.append('|'); // Add union separator if needed
    for (int i = 0; i < delim.length(); i++) {
      // Add an escape character if the character is a regexp reserved char
      regexpr.append('\\');
      regexpr.append(delim.charAt(i));
    }
  }
  regexpr.append(')'); // Close the union
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexpr.toString());

  // Now, search for the tokens
  List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
  Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
  int pos = 0;
  while (m.find()) { // While there's a delimiter in the string
    if (pos != m.start()) {
      // If there's something between the current and the previous delimiter
      // Add it to the tokens list
      res.add(string.substring(pos, m.start()));
    }
    res.add(m.group()); // add the delimiter
    pos = m.end(); // Remember end of delimiter
  }
  if (pos != string.length()) {
    // If it remains some characters in the string after last delimiter
    // Add this to the token list
    res.add(string.substring(pos));
  }
  // Return the result
  return res.toArray(new String[res.size()]);
}
```

It could be optimize if you have many strings to tokenize by creating the Pattern only one time.

Comment: `String.split` lets you specify a regex for splitting.

Comment: Do you want to keep the spaces or ignore them?

Comment: Yes, I prefer (in fact I have a list of delimiters, and space is just a delimiter as other).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and a simple loop to achieve the results that you are looking for:

```
List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([&]{1,2}|=>?| +)");
String s = "s=a&=>b";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
int pos = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    if (pos != m.start()) {
        res.add(s.substring(pos, m.start()));
    }
    res.add(m.group());
    pos = m.end();
}
if (pos != s.length()) {
    res.add(s.substring(pos));
}
for (String t : res) {
    System.out.println("'"+t+"'");
}
```

This [produces](http://ideone.com/WwR5O) the result below:

```
's'
'='
'a'
'&'
'=>'
'b'
```

Comment: If you use those characters in the `split` they'll never come up in the resulting array, e.g., `&`, `&&`, et cetera.

Comment: @João You are absolutely right, I did not notice this part of the question. This is now fixed. Thanks for the note!

Comment: @Jean-MarcAstesana That's a relatively easy change - please see the edit.

Comment: Nice it works. Thanks again. As I am a dummy with regular expressions, I'm still wondering how I can build the regexpr from my token delimiter list (the delimiters I've provided were just an example). If you have a piece of code for converting a delimiters array in a regexp, it would be absolutly perfect.

Comment: @Jean-MarcAstesana You build regular expressions manually most of the time. The simplest "template" for you would be `(delim1|delim2|delim3)` and so on. I combined `&|&&` into `[&]{1,2}`, but the simplified form would work as well. The same deal is with `=|=>`: I used `=>?` meaning that `>` is optional, but the other form would work just as well. Be careful with delimiters that represent regex metacharacters: `(`, `[`, `]`, `)`, `$`, `^`, and so on. You need to prefix them with a pair of slashes (one for the Java, one for regex), like this: `\\[|\\]`.

Comment: Thanks (one more time). There was a trap: The delimiters have to be sorted in the regexpr in order to have longer delimiters before shorter (&& should be before &). Anyway, my problem is totally solved. I will post the complete code of my tokenizer, to have a ready to use solution for the next generations ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Split won't do it for you as it removed the delimeter. You probably need to tokenize the string on your own (i.e. a for-loop) or use a framework like 
http://www.antlr.org/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String test = "a & b&&c=>d=A";
String regEx = "(&[&]?|=[>]?)";

String[] res = test.split(regEx);
for(String s : res){
    System.out.println("Token: "+s);
}
```

I added the '=A' at the end to show that that is also parsed.

As mentioned in another answer, if you need the atypical behaviour of keeping the delimiters in the result, you will probably need to create you parser yourself....but in that case you really have to think about what a "delimiter" is in your code.